# Why are Google Cloud Function runtime variables not coming through?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

This should be extremely straightforward, but I'm stuck. I'm building a v2 Cloud Function, https trigger, Compute Engine default service account, and I set Runtime environment variables as seen in the screenshot below, but they don't get created in my runtime environment.

[image]

My code:

```
@functions_framework.http
def save_to_mongodb(request):
    print("Function invoked")
    print(os.environ.get("TESTING")
```

Output::

[image]

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm answering my own question here, after more testing I found that if I deploy the function and use the "TESTING" tab in the "Function details" screen, the runtime env variables come across fine. When trying to access them in the "Edit function" screen where it launches a Cloud Shell Terminal, they are not accessible.

It's not clear to me if this is expected behavior or documented anywhere.